# How to access the App Drawer on Ulefone Note 14 Pro?

Tags: app-drawer, ulefone

Switched to a new(ish) phone:

> Unlocked Cell Phone (2022), Ulefone Note 14 Pro Smartphone Unlocked, 4GB+64GB, 6.52" Waterdrop Display, 4500mAh Battery, 13MP Dual Camera, Android 12, Triple Card Slots, Type-C, GPS, Green

from Amazon but cannot locate the [App Drawer](https://www.guidingtech.com/what-app-drawer-android/).

Certainly, I can go to settings -> apps to see all apps.  What I'm looking for are the icons to apps which I can drag-and-drop so that they're copied to the home screen.

Where is the app drawer?

*Not all apps seem available by swiping left and right.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andrew_T's answer was the right one, i cannot see it now any more. Long press on the home screen, then in the settings choose all apps in app drawer instead of all apps on home screen. Thanks!