# How to troubleshoot Easy Launch not accessing SMS messages on Ulefone?

Tags: applications, sms, launcher, ulefone

Adapting to a Ulephone and am using the built-in "Easy Launch" app for [organizing](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250228/316457) the apps.  The icon to launch the text messenger stopped functioning for no apparent reason.

There's no information on this app which I could readily find.  When a button such as this stops working, what are the steps to find the cause and fix it?

Comment: For those who are not familiar with "Easy Launch" on Ulefone, is it like the one shown in [Oukitel's promotional YouTube video](https://youtu.be/QxIoPyh-BnA?t=156)? Also, are there any SMS apps installed, like Messaging? Lastly, are there "default app" options in Android Settings?

Comment: I use Google Web Messenger, and will check the default apps in settings.  I've also cleared the cache for this "Easy Launch" with no effect.

Comment: By Google Web Messenger, did you mean accessing [this page from browser](https://messages.google.com/web/) or the [Google Messaging](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging) app? If that's the case, then probably there's no SMS app installed/enabled, thus the button doesn't work. I can't really say anything about "Easy Launcher" because it looks like a manufacturer-dependent app and as you've mentioned, no manual or guide about it.