# Remove app icon from home screen on Redmi Note 10, MIUI 14

Tags: xiaomi, home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen, miui

I want to remove the YouTube app icon but Android doesn't let me (apps in settings only mentioned uninstalling all updates) since it's a default app. I can only uninstall apps which I've downloaded.

Specifications: Android 13.TKQ1.221013.002, MIUI 14.0.1, Redmi Note 10 Pro

The images below show what happens if you long-press default apps vs downloaded apps.

[image] [image]

Here is the app info for the installed vs default app. Once again, no option to disable it, you can only uninstall updates.

[image] [image]

Comment: Does long-pressing and dragging an icon to the top or bottom not show a trash icon where you can drag it further?

Comment: On common app launchers you can simply remove the app icon no matter if the app is installed or not. But AFIR MIUI is an iPhone clone so it displays always all apps. But you should be able to disable pre-installed system apps which should remove the icon. Check the the App Info page.

Comment: @Firelord It does for installed apps but not pre-installed ones.

Comment: @Robert Unfortunately app info doesn't have that option, see the update. App permissions doesn't have anything either.

Comment: I kind of remember someone else commenting similar to Robert's about the "iPhone clone". If that's the case, then one alternative solution is to install a 3rd-party home screen/launcher app. Otherwise, if you don't want YouTube at all, then try [uninstalling the app using `pm uninstall --user 0`](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/186586/44325)

Comment: Kind of bizarre that [the question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250228/44325) to the comment I was looking for was suddenly bumped. That question mentioned [this link](https://www.guidingtech.com/what-app-drawer-android/) which says: "*Only some stock launchers like Mi Launcher don’t offer an app drawer*", and thus all app icons are placed on the home screen.